# Can't install Nokogiri for Ruby in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, nokogiri, devkit

I know this is simple but I just can't figure it out. I need to run a script in Ruby and it requires Nokogiri. I do have some experience in other languages but not in Ruby.

Here is my system :

> Ruby 2.0.0-p195 (x64) is installed @ *C:\Programs\RubyLanguage*
>
> Ruby Development Kit (mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432) is installed @ *C:\Programs\RubyDevKit*

When I run `gem install nokogiri` I get this error:

```
    ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        The 'nokogiri' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

Easy enough. So I followed [the link of above](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) and did to step 3. However step 4 says generate "config.yml". So I did. Now the file is an empty list with some comments. I still can't install Nokogiri because of error above and I don't seem to get anywhere with DevKit . What I am saying is that the steps in the Development Kit installation is not clear enough for me.

---

**Update** it now says installation of Nokogiri failed ( DevKit Works according to step 5 : Installing documentation for json-1.8.0
1 gem installed )

```
mkmf.log: package configuration for libxslt is not found
package configuration for libxml-2.0 is not found
package configuration for libiconv is not found
find_header: checking for libxml/parser.h... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/libxml2 -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -DXP_WIN -DXP_WIN32 -DUSE_INCLUDED_VASPRINTF -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/lib -LC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/lib -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi   "
In file included from C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:153:0,
                 from C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from conftest.c:1:
C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h: In function 'rb_w32_pow':
C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/win32.h:776:16: warning: conversion to 'double' from 'long double' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
In file included from C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from conftest.c:1:
C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_float_value':
C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:777:6: warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]
C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:777:6: warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include/libxml2 -IC:/Programs/RubyLanguage/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -DXP_WIN -DXP_WIN32 -DUSE_INCLUDED_VASPRINTF -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:27: fatal error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <libxml/parser.h>
/* end */
```

**CMD log**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\SEPEHR>gem install nokogiri
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokog
iri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/bin/ruby
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --with-iconv-dir
        --without-iconv-dir
        --with-iconv-include
        --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
        --with-iconv-lib
        --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
        --with-xml2-dir
        --without-xml2-dir
        --with-xml2-include
        --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
        --with-xml2-lib
        --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
        --with-xslt-dir
        --without-xslt-dir
        --with-xslt-include
        --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
        --with-xslt-lib
        --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
        --with-libxslt-config
        --without-libxslt-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libxml-2.0-config
        --without-libxml-2.0-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libiconv-config
        --without-libiconv-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/
gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Programs/RubyLanguage/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6
.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Comment: You absolutely _need_ DevKit installed to work with Nokogiri on windows (unless you happen to have other compilation tools installed, which doesn't appear to be the case).  Instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit).  What exactly isn't working for you with the DevKit installation?

Comment: I recommend using ruby 1.9.3, 2.0 on windows is a dicey proposition at this time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update: As of version 1.6.2, Nokogiri now **does** support the 64-bit version of Ruby 2.0.0.  (Note that it requires  libxml >= 2.6.21 )

Here's the answer if you still need to install the x86 version for some reason or if you want to understand how to install and build a gem using DevKit:

---

<s>Nokogiri does not yet support the **64-bit** version of Ruby 2.0.0.</s> You can read about it and [follow the status here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/864).

But Nokogiri **does** support the **x86** version of ruby 2.0.0.  You should be able to install the gem in on 2.0.0 x86 install.

It's pretty easy to hand-install.  I prefer that over RailsInstaller because I need to maintain other things as they are.  Here's how:

1. Download and unzip the files for the version you need. Be sure to [download the correct version of DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) for the x86 version of 2.0.0.
2. Fix your path:  Make sure your path includes the directories to the right ruby, gem, and DevKit dirs:
   Assume you installed the x86 version of ruby 2.0.0 into `C:\rubies\ruby-2-0-0-x86` and the associated DevKit into `C:\rubies\DevKit-xxxx-x86` you will need to include these directories in your PATH:

   C:\rubies\ruby-2-0-0-x86\bin
   C:\rubies\ruby-2-0-0-x86\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0
   C:\rubies\DevKit-xxxx-x86\bin
3. Inject DevKit into the right ruby install:  Once you have ruby installed and can get the correct info when you type `ruby -v`, then run `ruby dk.rb init` -- which will get DevKit set up & 'injected' into the correct ruby version.  (N.B. I always have to edit the `config.yml` file that is produced and put in the correct path to the ruby installation I want. Don't sweat it if you need to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

Yup ... Downgrading to 1.9.3 worked . Tnx for help . I put the summary here :

- Install Ruby 1.9.3 ( Do not change Install Name to ex.RubyLang or
  config doesn't find it automatically )
- Install DevKit (Follow DevKit    Installation Steps)
- Install Nokogiri

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to install x64 Nokogiri for Ruby 2.0 on Windows 7, but the [binary gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/pull/989#issuecomment-29111842) seems to be working.