# ROR installation not able to install properly

Tags: ruby

**ROR installation not able to install properly **

Rails server not connected after shutdown system, even I entered the command `rails s`.

Could anyone please the correct way to manage Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Could you please provide some more specific information?  What happens when you run `rails s`? Are you getting an error?  If so, please copy and paste that error as part of your answer so that we can help you.

Comment: after execution of cmd rails s its getting stop next execution  i mean its  getting hang the execution and not able to give next cmd

Comment: Can you paste your error at least

Comment: its kind of gems installation not completed and nokogiri  . However i gave the cmd for Gems still i am not able to connect it properly with mysql 



See Error::
cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

    C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri
    .rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'\

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you did not install `nokogiri` on your system. You need to do that before you try to run the rails server.

If you are on Mac OSX, try a command like this to install `nokogiri`(make the version change according to your need):

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries=true --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
```

Then, try to run `rails s` command again.

You may also want to take a look at the [official page for nokogiri installation.](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

Comment: I used this command but still not working..I am using ROR on my window 7

Comment: Could you  please provide  me any link or any command note for install it properly on my window 7.As i Delete all previous files for new installation.i want it begin.

Comment: Take a look at the answers from these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6455843/981183, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18157970/981183. That may help.